# Finding the closed form of the product $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} (1 - 1/q^{i}) $.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, infinite-product, random-matrices

I would like to know what is the closed form of the following product if it exists:

$$
\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \Big(1 - \frac{1}{q^{i}}\Big).
$$

I gave it a little time but only managed to establish some pretty obviuos bounds:

$$
\frac{q - 2}{q - 1} < \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \Big(1 - \frac{1}{q^{i}}\Big) < \frac{q - 1}{q}.
$$

If anyone is interested in a context - this is connected to full rank matrices over the finite field $F_{q}$. Particularly if we will pick square matrices of dimension $n$ over this field uniformly, then this product with $n$ in the place of infinity is the probability of finding a full rank matrix.

So if anyone has a suggestion related to how this probability can be calculated without resorting to finding this product, then I will also be glad to see it.

Comment: For dimension $n$, the probability is not the infinite product, but the product of the first $n$ terms.

Comment: I think the sum is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{p(n)}{q^n}$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$, so this should help get better approximations.

Comment: @mathworker21 That would be the *inverse* of the product, by the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem#Partition_recurrence).

Comment: @Servaes yes, i meant inverse. I just derived it directly

Comment: @Servaes, yes, of course, made corrections in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "closed form". The infinite product $\;\prod_{i = 1}^\infty (1 - \frac{1}{q^{i}}) = f(-1/q)\;$ where $f()$ is a [Ramanujan theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function). Other notation is $(1/q;1/q)_\infty\;$ which uses what is called [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol). As for calculating its value, in [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) it is $\;\texttt{eta(log(1/q)/(2*Pi*I))}.$

Comment: Well, the form that doesn't use any special functions would be nice. It's just that I'm not at all familiar with number theory and the problem seemed tractable but mathworker21's and Servaes's comments as well as your answer suggest that there is no way to get a nice concise formula.